# Python: How to add main column header for multiple column headings?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have this data set:

```
data={'a1':[1,2,3,4,5],'a2':[4,5,6,7,8],'b1':[2,5,3,7,9],'b2':[7,5,8,9,3],'c1':[2,4,5,7,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

How can i script python if I would like to add main column headers to the existing column headings. For instance, 'a1' & 'a2 will be categorized under 'A', 'be' & 'b2' will be categorized under 'B' and 'c1' remains alone.
For example:

[image]

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: can you upvote/mark as answer or do you need clarification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
data={'a1':[1,2,3,4,5],'a2':[4,5,6,7,8],'b1':[2,5,3,7,9],'b2':[7,5,8,9,3],'c1':[2,4,5,7,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns=[['a','a','b','b','c'],['a1','a2','b1','b2','c1']]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**pd.MultiIndex**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) for adding another level of header

```
columns=[('a','a1'),('a','a2'),('b','b1'),('b','b2'),('c','c')]
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
```

Comment: This gives an error as there are 5 columns in the data and there are only four items in your list

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar updated, it's working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign values to `df.columns` to get the desired output. You also get a single `C` for the `c1` column:

```
df.columns = [[i[0].upper() for i in data.keys()], list(data.keys())]
```

Output:

```
   A     B     C
  a1 a2 b1 b2 c1
0  1  4  2  7  2
1  2  5  5  5  4
2  3  6  3  8  5
3  4  7  7  9  7
4  5  8  9  3  5
```

Comment: @Win does this answer your question?